# paddleboard chafing

Tags: paddle-boards

I have searched the internet high and low and I haven't found a lot of good answers. Has anyone had to deal with chafing from their paddleboard causing rashes on their legs? What do you do to prevent it? I am not advanced enough to stand on my paddleboard for extended periods of time so I spend a lot of time sitting or kneeling on my board. Will my rashes go away once I start standing on it more regularly? Should I just wear swim pants in the meantime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the site.

I'd recommend a rash suit or wet-suit if you are in warm or cold locations respectively. Once your skin is out of contact with the board, it should stop getting rubbed (so badly) and the rashes should stop.

I'm guessing that the rashes are occurring on your upper legs, so a pair of shorts may suffice, but beware of getting sand in the legs as this can exacerbate rubbing.